# How to attach raise_()'d and move()'d QWidget to the right border of the parent's widget in PySide6

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyside

Is it possible to set position for `raise_()`'d widget relative to the right edge of the parent's frame?
The main goal is to place button/checkbox in the top-right corner of the QChartView.
The problem is that i can't glue the button to the right border. Button simply deattaches itself after window resizing.
I want to create the same behaviour as a default `move()`'d button has, but relative to the right border (in default, widget relate to the left border and moves with it when window is resized).

Here is the basic example.

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QCheckBox, QVBoxLayout
from PySide6.QtCore import QMargins
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(600, 400)
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('QRadioButton in QChartView')
        self.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        chart_view = QChartView(self)
        chart = QChart()
        series = QLineSeries()
        chart.legend().setVisible(False)
        series.append(0, 6)
        series.append(2, 4)
        series.append(3, 8)
        series.append(7, 4)
        series.append(10, 5)
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.createDefaultAxes()
        chart_view.setChart(chart)
        chart_view.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        chart.setMargins(QMargins(10, 10, 20, 10))
        chart.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        # Left button behaviour (aligns left top)
        radio_button_left = QCheckBox('', self)
        radio_button_left.setMinimumSize(13, 13)
        radio_button_left.setMaximumSize(13, 13)
        radio_button_left.move(33, 23)

        # Right button behaviour (aligns left top, but I want to make it align right top)
        radio_button_right = QCheckBox('', self)
        radio_button_right.setMinimumSize(13, 13)
        radio_button_right.setMaximumSize(13, 13)
        radio_button_right.move(self.width()-33, 23)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(chart_view)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        chart_view.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is an example of correct right button placement:
[image]

And here what happens if i resize the window.
[image]

The reason why i want to do this is because I have too much empty space on the right border of the chart (numbers on the X axis can go beyond the boundary of the chart and shift the chart. I don't want to crop them.).
And as long as i need the button on the top right corner, i decided to place button on the top of the QChartView, to use this empty space efficiently.
So, how can i solve the problem?

**Important**: I don't really want to write position recalculation function related on window width, bc this will be overpriced.

Answer (score 0):

Geometries always consider positions based on their origin point, which in UI development is normally the top left corner of the context (parent, screen, etc.). If you set fixed positions, the widgets will always stay at their position unless told otherwise.

Writing a "position recalculation" is really not a big deal, avoiding that is just laziness. Besides, that's exactly what a layout manager does, and for such a simple case it's just a matter of overriding `resizeEvent()` and do the same thing you did in the `__init__`; you just need to keep a reference to the button you have to move:

```py
    ...
    def initUI(self):
        ...
        self.radio_button_right = QCheckBox()
        ...

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self.radio_button_right.move(self.width() - 33, 23)
```

Still, you can do that with proper layout management too, and one possibility is to use a QGridLayout as main layout: one peculiar feature of such layout is that widgets (and child layouts) can be added to grid cells that are already occupied by other items.

The trick is to add the chart to the first cell of the grid layout, and a QHBoxLayout to the *same* cell, specifying the vertical (top) alignment for that; then the buttons will be added to the horizontal layout (with a stretch item in the middle) and proper contents margins for that layout will then be used to set their distance from the border.

Note that you should avoid to set fixed geometries for widgets using arbitrary values: the 13x13 size you are using for the buttons is wrong because it's only based on assumed sizes instead of considering the current style. In my computer I can only see a small part of them, because the default style I use has much larger indicators for check boxes.

The proper minimum size of such widgets should use their `minimumSizeHint()`; then, if you want to avoid the common spacing used between the indicator of radio buttons and check boxes and their text (which is always present even if no text is set), you can specify a 0-spacing using style sheets.

```py
        radio_button_left = QCheckBox(styleSheet='spacing: 0px')
        radio_button_right = QCheckBox(styleSheet='spacing: 0px')
        size = radio_button_left.minimumSizeHint()
        radio_button_left.setFixedSize(size)
        radio_button_right.setFixedSize(size)

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(chart_view)

        overlay = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(overlay, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

        overlay.setContentsMargins(33, 23, 33, 0)
        overlay.addWidget(radio_button_left)
        overlay.addStretch()
        overlay.addWidget(radio_button_right)
```

<sup>Unrelated notes: 1. while similar in concept, radio buttons and check boxes have important differences in purpose and behavior, and their display reflects that (meaning that the user expects a specific behavior depending on what they see): always choose them for the right reason and don't confuse their names; 2. there is no point in creating a widget specifying a parent if it will be added to a layout; 3. calling `show()` such widgets is pointless too: remember to only call visibility functions with awareness.</sup>